# Ajax call not returning expected value

Tags: javascript, ajax

Stuck on why this isn't working, anyone got any ideas? It should update the button and i think it does, just displays the else at the end all the time

```
    function friendToggle(type,user,elem){
    var conf = confirm("Press Ok to confirm the '" +type+ "' action for user " + user);
    if(conf != true){
        return false;
    }

    O(elem).innerHTML = 'please wait...';

    params = user
    request = new ajaxRequest()
    request.open("POST", "friendSystem.php", true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4){
            if(this.responseText == "friend_request_sent"){
                O(elem).innerHTML = 'OK Friend Request Sent';
            }else if(this.responseText == "unfriend_ok"){
                O(elem).innerHTML = '<button onclick="friendToggle(\'friend\',\'echo $view;\',\'friendBtn\')">Request As Friend</button>';
            }else {
                alert(request.responseText);
                O(elem).innerHTML = 'Try again later';
            }
        }   
    }   
request.send("type="+type+"&user="+user);
```

}

This is the code it calls:

```
if($_POST['type'] == "friend")
{
    $friendCount = mysqli_fetch_row(querySQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends WHERE user='$user' AND accepted='1' OR friend='$user' AND accepted='1'"));

    $blockCount1 = mysqli_fetch_row(querySQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blockedusers WHERE blocker='$user' AND blockee='$view' LIMIT 1"));

    $blockCount2 = mysqli_fetch_row(querySQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blockedusers WHERE blocker='$view' AND blockee='$user' LIMIT 1"));

    $rowCount1 = mysqli_fetch_row(querySQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends WHERE user='$view' AND friend='$user' AND accepted='1' LIMIT 1"));

    $rowCount2 = mysqli_fetch_row(querySQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends WHERE user='$user' AND friend='$view' AND accepted='1' LIMIT 1"));

    $rowCount3 = mysqli_fetch_row(querySQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends WHERE user='$view' AND friend='$user' AND accepted='0' LIMIT 1"));

    $rowCount4 = mysqli_fetch_row(querySQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends WHERE user='$user' AND friend='$view' AND accepted='0' LIMIT 1"));

    if($friendCount[0] > 99){
        echo"$user currently has the maximum number of friends and cannot accept any more";
    }elseif($blockCount1[0] > 0){
        echo "$user has you blocked, we cannot proceed.";
    }elseif($blockCount2[0] > 0){
        echo"You must first unblock $user in order to friend them.";
    }elseif($rowCount1[0] >0 || $rowCount2[0] > 0){
        echo"You are already friends with $user.";
    }elseif($rowCount3[0] >0){
        echo"You have a pending friend request already sent to $user.";
    }elseif($rowCount4[0] > 0){
        echo"$user has requested to friend with you first. Check your friend requests";
    }else{
        querySQL("INSERT INTO friends VALUES('$user','$view','0')");
        echo"friend_request_sent";
    }

}
```

its meant to echo the correct error message, but doesn't. Also will never send the friend request sent message

Comment: Apparently the `responseText` is neither `friend_request_sent` nor `unfriend_ok`.  Not sure what you want us do. If you are indeed sending back the correct response, provide more information about the issue. Otherwise, update your client side code to match the responses you get from the server, or update your server side code to return the correct responses.

Comment: Add `alert(this.responseText);` before your `if(this.responseText == "friend_request_sent")` and compare your results !

Comment: Geoffrey, it had no effect, just comes up with a blank alert box and no response text, even though this person isn't a friend yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Content-length isn't right. It's set to the length of `user` but you send more than that in the POST data. It seems the web server is cutting your data up to the wrong length, then can't parse the malformed string.

Make your POST data into a variable, so you can get the length without duplicating it:

```
var data = "type="+encodeURIComponent(type)+"&user="+encodeURIComponent(user);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
```

Then when you call send:

```
request.send(data);
```

---

Side note: added `encodeURIComponent` to properly encode the values.

Comment: getting this error in debug
Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

Comment: Before the line `if($_POST['type'] == "friend")` in the PHP, do `var_dump($_POST);` to see what's being received.

Comment: POST https://dunluce.infc.ulst.ac.uk/B00677090/com302/GroupAssignment/friendSystem.php
 
200 OK
  35ms 
jquery-... > eval (line 140)
HeadersPostHTMLCookies
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencodedDo not sort
type 
friend
user 
LyndsRob2
Source
type=friend&user=LyndsRob2

Comment: That looks ok, check the response tab to see what the PHP is outputting.

Comment: in the response headers i get this ouptut in firebug
Connection 
Keep-Alive
Content-Length 
0
Content-Type 
text/html
Date 
Thu, 30 Apr 2015 17:58:15 GMT
Keep-Alive 
timeout=5, max=82
Server 
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2 PHP/5.5.11
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.5.11

Comment: content-length is 0, seems like its not getting through somewhere in the friendsSystem page.....

Comment: Found the issue, i was using include_once at the top of the file, there was some issue in the file it was loading, i created a new file with just the database connection information and user login checks and it worked fine.. Thanks for your help!!